# fetch images from FTP server using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to fetch some images that are stored in a FTP server, using Google Apps Script

The images are accessible only by FTP as

```
ftp://user:password@ftpsite.com/path2photos/photo123.jpg
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried URLFetch ? If yes, what results did you see ?

Comment: AFAIK, UrlFetchApp only works with HTTP/HTTPS, not with FTP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to make outbound FTP requests from Google Apps Script (there is a similar restriction from App Engine as well).

You are options are either to find an HTTP interface to the server (some sites offer both HTTP and FTP), or download the files through an FTP client and then upload to Google Drive and then access those files from there.

Feel free to look for/log an item in the [Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).

Comment: thanks Arun, just wanted to be sure, I do agree with that restriction > I will look for another approach

Answer (score -2):

I have successfully gotten images off of remote servers into google apps script via the use of the UrlFetchApp Class.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app

Comment: Using ftp, as the question indicates? Kindly provide an example.