# How to upload any file to FTP Server using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, ftp

I have attachments in my Gmail mail threads and i have written code to get attachments from mail and i am trying to upload it on a FTP location using Google script but it seems there is no suitable API provided for it.

Please suggest any other methods to solve this problem using google script.

Comment: It seems Apps script only supports HTTP requests, you can probably do something similar to this, sending the content of the file from apps script to a service of your own and then send the file from your service to the FTP server. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894694/fetch-images-from-ftp-server-using-google-apps-script

Comment: you can also check the issue related to this topic: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2379

Comment: Related [Upload file via FTP using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29944387/1595451)