# Reading data from a .txt file and FTP server

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, ftp

I'm trying to make a Google Sheets to follow up my investments. To do it I need to get some information from this URL: `ftp://ftp.cetip.com.br/IndiceDI/`. From that I need a function that accesses the specific link and fetches the number inside it. Something like this:

```
function = getTxt(URL)

...

return number
```

The URL follows a pattern: ftp://ftp.cetip.com.br/IndiceDI/YYYMMDD.txt

Where YYYY is the **YEAR**; MM is the **MONTH**; and DD is the **DAY**. Its easy the edit the URL, but Im facing some trouble to get that number =/

I've already tried the `XmlHttpRequest()` but it's not enabled in Google Sheets.

I'll use this number to do some calculations. I'll need to get two of these and divide one by another to return the gain in that period of time, but it's very easy to do.

Comment: You can't directly use a js code to retrieve data from another site and put inside a spreadsheet. To do that you will need to use [google API specific for google-spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

External requests in Apps Script are done using UrlFetchApp, however [this does not support FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894694/fetch-images-from-ftp-server-using-google-apps-script)